# What is this syntax and how to debug it?

Tags: php, add-on, expressionengine

I am currently working on moving an expression engine site from one server to another and i noticed one issue i am having a hardtime debugging. When i upload an logo image all seems fine but the index.php page that the logo is displayed on it has this code

```
{embed="shared/head"}

<body class="{if segment_1 == ''}home{if:else}{segment_1}{/if}">

    <div id="page" class="container">
        <div class="span-22 prepend-1 append-1 last">

            {embed="shared/masthead"}
{if logo !=''}
  <div class="news_item_logo">
    {organization}
      {if link}<a href="http://{exp:php_text_format type="lowercase"}{if url !=''}{url}{if:else}{name}{/if}{/exp:php_text_format}"><img src="{logo}" width="130" alt="{title}" /></a>{if:else}
      <img src="{logo}" width="130" alt="{title}" />{/if}
    {/organization}
  </div><!-- /.news_item_logo -->
  <ul>
    <li><h3>{title}</h3></li>
    <li>{pub_date}</li>
  {organization}
    <li>{if link}<a href="http://{if url !=''}{url}{if:else}{name}{/if}">{/if}{exp:php_text_format type="lowercase"}{if url_text != ''}{url_text}{if:else}{name}{/if}{if link}{/exp:php_text_format}</a>{/if}</li>
  {/organization}
    <li>{if file}<a href="{site_url}{file}">PDF</a>{/if}{if web_link !='' AND file !=''}&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;{/if}{if web_link}<a href="{web_link}">HTML</a>{/if}</li>
  </ul>
{if:else}
  <ul class="no_logo">
    <li><h3><a href="{web_link}">{title}</a></h3></li>
```

My question is this, I see curly brackets {} around if statements and i want to know first what language it is and second is there a way to debug like php print_r() because the code always goes to the else with the no_logo class and i want to know what and how i can test these variables "segment1" and "logo" and "organization" and "url" How do and where do i inspect these variables

Comment: I don't recognise it, but you should be able to find what the page is running through that evaluates it.

Comment: If you look at the code as it is here, you'll see that there's a syntax error: missing quote.

Comment: Oops, after closer inspection apparently there is none.  I guess the system just doesn't recognize the syntax and the highlighting went a little wonky.

Answer (score 3):

You can gain some info about the given variables and values in the template using the following within your index.php:

```
<?php

$EE = get_instance();
var_dump($this->EE->TMPL);

?>
```

Note that PHP must be enabled in templates for that to work (see [PHP in Templates](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/php_templates.html)).

Answer (score 3):

`{embed="shared/head"}` - include the template **head** from the template group **shared**

`<body class="{if segment_1 == ''}home{if:else}{segment_1}{/if}">`

if the URI segment (EE/CI works with segments eg site.com/segment1/segment2/xxx) is empty (you are on the home page (www.site.com), then add no body class.

else, the user is on a page (in EE this is a template group), so set the class to be the name of the template group.

`site.com/about-us` produces `class="about-us"` - handy for page specific styling.

`{embed="shared/masthead"}` - include **masthead**

and so on.

The rest are conditionals to check if the variables have values, and outputs them

I presume you're using EE2.0, I'm not sure what `{organizaton}` is specifically, but that style:

`{organization} {foo} {/organization}`

in code igniter at least, is generally the equivalent of a foreach or looping through a recordset:

`foreach($organizations as $organization) { // do something }`

Comment: This is the one answer that is from someone that understands Expression Engine.

Answer (score 2):

This is written in Expression Engine's own [templating language](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/overview/templates.html).

You would have to check the documentation to see whether there is any way to debug variables.

Possibly helpful links:

- [Quick Reference Chart](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/quick_reference.html)
- [PHP in Templates](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/php_templates.html)